# Add/Remove Swing jList (built with Netbeans GUI builder)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jlist

I know the question of how to add an element to a jList has been asked.  Yet...this is a bit different as I've been using NetBeans GUI builder.  It instantiates my two lists as AbstractListModels.  Then I can't seem to add an element from one list, to the other, then remove that element from the first list.

The JList:

```
colors1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        colors1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "red", "yellow", "green", "blue", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(colors1);

        colors2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        colors2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "black", "white", "gray", "brown", " ", " ", " " };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(colors2);
```

My attempt to cast to defaultlistmodel and add an element (haven't gotten to removing yet).

```
 private void addColorsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        DefaultListModel list1 = (DefaultListModel) colors1.getModel();
        DefaultListModel list2 = (DefaultListModel) colors2.getModel();
        list2.addElement( colors1.getSelectedValue());
        //Haven't actually attempted this yet but if I had would look like. 
        //list1.removeElement(colors1.getSelectedValue());
    }
```

Comment: 1- Don't use Netbeans form editor or 2- Don't pre-fill the model with values, do it after the `initComponent` method and use a `DefaultListModel`

Comment: 3- Use the "code" option to inject your own code into the creation process; 4- Click the "..." button in the "model" property, select "Custom code" from the "Set ... model property using" combobox and inject your own code

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use Netbeans form editor or
2. Don't pre-fill the model with values, do it after the `initComponent` method and use a `DefaultListModel`or
3. Use the "code" option on the property sheet editor to inject your own code into the creation process or
4. Click the <kbd>...</kbd> button in the "model" property, select "Custom code" from the "Set ... model property using" combobox and inject your own code, create your own `ListModel`, probably using a `DefaultListModel`

The basic process of defining your own model, which supports dynamic updating, remains the same regardless of whether you created the `JList` manually or through Netbeans, you just need to decide on the best place to inject your code